# How to debug Android apps on Samsung gts5360 device via Windows 7

Tags: android, windows, usb

I want to debug Android app on Samsung gts5360 device via Windows 7. USB debugging on Android side is enabled, but device is not showing in Eclipse when connected. I had no such problems in Ubuntu.
So please suggest me how to debug apps on Android device via Window 7?

Comment: Have you installed drivers first?

Comment: Its not possible... How would you run Android Apps on Win7 Phone

Comment: @Ahmad, where do you see here *Win7 phone*?

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Please tell me in deep i have given permission of device in sdk

Comment: Please rephrase your question - I really can't understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try resetting the adb. I usually run Dalvik Debug Monitor in the background when using connected devices, so I can verify that the AVD and/or devices really are registered. You'll find this tool in `C:\Program Files (x86)\android-sdk\tools` or wherever you have your Android SDK installed. It's called ddms.exe.

If you don't see your device there, go to the menu `Actions --> Reset asb`. Now, all AVDs and devices should popup, and it will be available in Eclipse. At least, this works for me.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but can you tell me where is Actions--->Reset asb or adb ?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot to mention that Dalvik Debug Monitor is the tool named `ddms.exe` in the `android-sdk/tools/` folder. Edited my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that its not working .What may be problem can you say.

Comment: Have you installed the Android USB driver for your device on your computer? See [this link on Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html).